# Bootstrap with spring mvc using gradle

Tags: java, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, gradle

I've written simpliest page using bootstrap. Now i want to run in using spring and gradle. I have added dependency

```
compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'bootstrap', version: '3.2.0'
```

into my build.gradle file. The only think i can't solve is what should i put in simplePage.html to force thymeleaf to resolve it. I wonder how to add

```
<link href="../../../../../../../Documents/js/first/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../../../Documents/js/first/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

using external libraries added with Gradle. These imports above i used to make bootstrap project locally.

Answer (score 1):

From [Webjars documentation for Sping Boot](http://www.webjars.org/documentation#springboot) :

> **Instructions for Spring Boot**
>
> [...]
>
> Then reference a WebJar asset like:
>
> ```
> <link rel='stylesheet' href='/webjars/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
> ```

Comment: How is it supposed to work when i dont even have /webjars/ dir?

Comment: Still according to the documentation, "Spring Boot automatically configures Spring to map requests for /webjars to the /META-INF/resources/webjars directory of all the JARs in the CLASSPATH."

Comment: I've tried to copy bootstrap to the /resources/static/ and changed each link to it, but still not working.

Comment: When you use webjars, you don't need to use static resources like bootstrap JS code and CSS code. Bootstrap webjar replaces static resources. You should really take a look to the documentation.